# xcode: application runs properly from Debug folder, but not if copied to any other folder

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a weirdness with my applescript application created in xcode.

When building for run, it runs properly. When copying the app from the Debug folder to another place, it does not run properly.

The application starts Photoshop, and then uses System Events UI scripting to open the Open File dialog. When not running from the Debug folder, it gets to start Photoshop, also activates System events, it seems to find the Photoshop process, but does not start with the UI scripting.

Being a noob, it baffles me, and I am stuck.

If further information is needed, please bear with me, and let me know what is needed.

Additional information: Another very similar application, which in particular uses exactly the same code, does work without issues.

Also, as asked in a comment, the application is given control to the machine in the Accessibility settings.

Edit: code as requested in comment

```
set myps to "com.adobe.Photoshop"
set applName to (get name of application id myps)

delay 1

tell application id myps
    -- activate
    using terms from application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            set ProcessList to name of every process
            if (applName is in ProcessList) then
                tell process applName
                    delay 0.8
                    display alert "here I am"
                    click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
                    delay 0.8
                    tell window 1
                    -- and so on
```

"`click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1`" opens the Open File dialog.

When running automatically after building or form the Debug (or Build) folder, that dialog opens; when running from elsewhere, the last thing I get is the "I am here" alert.

Also note that there is another block of code omitted, which uses a plist file to pass some parameters at runtime, but these parameters are needed only later in the script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you allowed the script in `System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility`?

Comment: Yes, the app is added to that list.

Comment: Show the code for your script, that's the only way to know of the problem most likely...

Comment: sandbox entitlements?

Comment: did you add try and Error Block? any Error thrown?

Comment: No sandbox entitlements, as far as I know; I started the project with default settings. No error thrown when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you need to build for release instead of debug.  To do this go to **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme**. Then click the **Run** tab on the side and change the `Build Configuration` to **Release**.

This will build an executable that *should be* completely self contained.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing those settings did not lead to any change.

Comment: Why do you need UI scripting at all? Build your own dialog and ask for  file(s). Then pass those pathes to photoshop. No need for UI scripting

Comment: @Pat_Morita UI scripting is necessary in this case; the open file dialog is not for my application, but I have to use it to open the file under specific conditions in Photoshop (actually, it is going to be the CameraRAW plug-in). Because that plug-in is not scriptable in any way, I end up with UI scripting. (of course, if you have a way to force open the file in the CameraRAW plug-in, I would be more than grateful to hear about it)